# how to pass parameters with Volley GET method

Tags: android, android-volley

How to pass parameters with `Volley` GET method?.

```
private void getData(int ClassIDs){
                                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
                                String url = "";
                                StringRequest request = new StringRequest(com.android.volley.Request.Method.GET, url,
                                        new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<String>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onResponse(String response) {
                                                Toast.makeText(ActivityStarsEntryTestPrep.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set GET volley request like this

```
 StringRequest commonRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url/* URL OF WEBSERVICE*/, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            //HANDLE RESPONSE
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            // Handle your error types accordingly.For Timeout & No
            // connection error, you can show 'retry' button.
            // For AuthFailure, you can re login with user
            // credentials.
            // For ClientError, 400 & 401, Errors happening on
            // client side when sending api request.
            // In this case you can check how client is forming the
            // api and debug accordingly.
            // For ServerError 5xx, you can do retry or handle
            // accordingly.

        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
             HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
             hashMap.put("KEY","VALUE");
             return hashMap;
        }
    };

    commonRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(5000, 1, 2));
    INSTANCE OF VOLLEY.addToRequestQueue(commonRequest);
```

This portion of code is useful for you

```
 {
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
         HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
         hashMap.put("KEY","VALUE");
         return hashMap;
    }
```

Comment: for me it's not working. According with this article https://mobikul.com/parameters-to-volley/, the getParams() method is calling only in the case of POST or PUT request. The GET request need to pass parameter in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full method I use to get string response using `Volley`. Use POST method if you pass parameters. Define your value and post URL. Get response using `onResponse` method.

```
public void getPostData() {
    String value = "value";
    String s; //to get response
    final String URL = "Your php URL paste here";

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                   s = response;
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(ActivityName.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            hashMap.put("value", value.toString);
            return hashMap;
        }
    };
    final RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    requestQueue.addRequestFinishedListener(new RequestQueue.RequestFinishedListener<Object>() {
        @Override
        public void onRequestFinished(Request<Object> request) {
            requestQueue.getCache().clear();
        }
    });
}
```